# Bad syntax in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, command-prompt

It is very late, and I'm tired at looking at this. Could someone explain where I might have bad syntax in this script?

The script looks to see if an old installation exists on a live machine within `computers.txt` file.  If so, it should uninstall it, copy over the new installation, and then install it.  If anything fails, log to its respective log file.

```
@echo off
:CheckifLogsExist
if NOT exist Uninstall.log (
    copy /y nul Uninstall.log
) else (
    del Uninstall.log && copy /y nul Uninstall.log
)

if NOT exist WMIC.log (
    copy /y nul WMIC.log
) else (
    del WMIC.log && copy /y nul WMIC.log
)

if NOT exist Copying.log (
    copy /y nul Copying.log
) else (
    del Copying.log && copy /y nul Copying.log
)

if NOT exist Install.log (
    copy /y nul Install.log
) else (
    del Install.log && copy /y nul Install.log
)

:checkifalive
for /F %%I IN (computers.txt) DO 
(
    ping -n 1 %%I 
    if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo Machine offline && goto:EOF

    :Uninstall
    echo "Uninstalling previous version of Symantec Endpoint Protection"
    psexec \\%%I -s wmic failfast:on product where name="Symantec Endpoint Protection" call uninstall /nointeractive
    if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo %%I  -  %errorlevel% >> Uninstall.log

    :copy
    echo "Finding out which processor is in the machine"
    wmic cpu list brief > temp.out
    findstr /I "86" temp.out && goto copy86 || goto copy64
    if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo %%I  -  %errorlevel% >> WMIC.log

    :copy86
    echo "Copying the installation to the local machine"
    copy "C:\installation.exe" \\%%I
    if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo %%I  -  %errorlevel% >> Copying.log
    goto Install86

    :copy64
    echo "Copying the installation to the local machine"
    copy "C:\installation.exe" \\%%I
    if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo %%I  -  %errorlevel% >> Copying.log
    goto Install64

    :Install86
    echo "Installing upgraded Symantec Endpoint Protection"
    psexec \\%%I -s "C:\installation.exe /s"
    if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo %%I  -  %errorlevel% >> Install.log
    goto Finish

    :Install64
    echo "Installing upgraded Symantec Endpoint Protection"
    psexec \\%%I -s "C:\installation.exe /s"
    if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo %%I  -  %errorlevel% >> Install.log
    goto Finish

    :Finish
)
```

Comment: I'm sure I'm sorry that it's late and you're tired, but you're going to need to give more information if you want help. Exactly what is the error, and at what point in the script? Have you tried running it with `@echo on` to see what it is doing on each line?

Comment: Also, I don't think this would cause syntax errors, but would cause it not to do what you are expecting - I don't think you can use gotos within a for loop like that in batch. You might do better with a subroutine for the actual installation part.

Comment: @Vicky is right: a `goto` breaks the loop. But you have another problem: you need delayed expansion for using variables inside a block. `%errorlevel%` is not, what you expect, it is the same value as before `for` and won't change between `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error is that these need to be on the same line, with a space after `do`

Note Stephan's comment that you also need to `enable delayed expansion` or as Vicky says use a `subroutine` that the `forindo` command will `call`

```
for /F %%I IN (computers.txt) DO 
(
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
:clear_logfiles   :: Label not needed
:: copy command doesn't care, if the file exists or not, it just (re)creates it with size 0:
copy /y nul Uninstall.log
copy /y nul WMIC.log
copy /y nul Copying.log
copy /y nul Install.log

:checkifalive  :: Label not needed
for /F %%I IN (computers.txt) DO ( call DoIt %%i )
echo all done.
goto :eof

REM this is the subroutine
:DoIt
  ping -n 1 %1
  if NOT %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo Machine offline
    goto :EOF
  )
  REM Uninstall
  echo "Uninstalling previous version of Symantec Endpoint Protection"
  psexec \\%1 -s wmic failfast:on product where name="Symantec Endpoint Protection" call uninstall /nointeractive
  if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo %1  -  %errorlevel% >> Uninstall.log

  REM copy
  echo "Finding out which processor is in the machine"
  wmic cpu list brief | findstr /I "86" 
  :: why checking for 86/64 if the code is exactly the same for both? Anyway - here we go:
  if %errorlevel%==0 ( call copy86 ) else ( call copy64 )
goto :eof

:copy86
  echo "Copying the installation to the local machine"
  copy "C:\installation.exe" \\%1
  if NOT %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo %1  -  %errorlevel% >> Copying.log
  ) else (
    REM Install86
    echo "Installing upgraded Symantec Endpoint Protection"
    psexec \\%1 -s "C:\installation.exe /s"
    if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo %1  -  %errorlevel% >> Install.log
  )
goto :eof

:copy64
  echo "Copying the installation to the local machine"
  copy "C:\installation.exe" \\%1
  if NOT %errorlevel%==0( 
    echo %1  -  %errorlevel% >> Copying.log 
  ) else (
    REM Install64
    echo "Installing upgraded Symantec Endpoint Protection"
    psexec \\%1 -s "C:\installation.exe /s"
    if NOT %errorlevel%==0 echo %1  -  %errorlevel% >> Install.log 
  )
goto :eof
```